# ExtJS add additional data into the post of a form

Tags: extjs

I have a simple ExtJS form, but I would like to add additional attributes to be sent as post data.

I have tried `form.setValues({name:value})` but for some reason it does not actually set the value...

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation for `setValues` says:

> > Set values for fields in this form in bulk.

From that I take it that the fields have to exist in the form for the values to be set, so
add hidden fields to the form. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.Hidden

You can do that in your `FormPanel` config or using `formPanel.add`

```
[{
  xtype: 'hidden',
  name: 'hidden1',
  value: 'hiddenValue1'
}, {
  xtype: 'hidden',
  name: 'hidden2',
  value: 'hiddenValue2'
}]
```

If you need to set the values dynamically, you can now use `form.setValues`.

Answer (score 7):

Also can directly add the additional value to submit parameter: url or params

like this:

```
this.theWindow.get(0).getForm().submit({
  url : 'youraction.action?name=value',
  success : function(form, action) {
     ...
  },
  failure : function(form, action) {
     ...
  }
}
```

or

```
this.theWindow.get(0).getForm().submit({
  url : 'youraction.action',
  params : {name : value},
  success : function(form, action) {
     ...
  },
  failure : function(form, action) {
     ...
  }
}
```